# Image src not changing in loop of javascript

Tags: javascript, html

```
function abc(){
    var i = 1;
    while(i<=6){
        var ImageSrc = i + ".png";
        console.log(ImageSrc);
        document.getElementsByName('faceImg')[0].src = ImageSrc;
        i += 1;
    }
}
```

I am calling this function to change image src dynamically. But only the last image is showing. Other images in the loops are not shown.

Comment: Could you post the html snippet? (al least the img tag)

Comment: What you need to do is add a parameter to the source address, something like, ?na=1, but make sure the value is incremented every time you change the request....if the image source is the same then it will not re-request the data, only if the URI changes.

Comment: It seems that you need to display images with a delay in between them which you should probably mention in your question.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are trying to display images going from 1 to 6 with a time interval in between each frame:

```js
let i = 1;

const timeInBetweenFrames = 1000; // Milliseconds
const imageSrc = "http://via.placeholder.com/450x250?text=";
const image = document.getElementsByName('faceImg')[0];

const incrementImage = () => {
  image.src = imageSrc + i;
  console.log(imageSrc + i);

  if (++i <= 6) {
     window.setTimeout(incrementImage, timeInBetweenFrames);
  }
};

incrementImage();
```

```html
<img name="faceImg" />
```

Comment: there is only one image tag and i have used name attribute. that's why i used document.getElementsByName('faceImg')[0].src = ImageSrc;

Comment: what are you trying to do exactly, right now you are assigning your image and overriding it 5 times. So of course only the last image will be displayed

Comment: @ShashankK Edited my answer

Comment: The timeout on first call might not be needed

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
document.getElementsByName('faceImg')[0].src = ImageSrc;
```

to

```
document.getElementsByName('faceImg')[i].src = ImageSrc;
```

Answer (score 1):

The loop would execute within a fraction of a second so you can only see the last image, to change with some delay use [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval).

```js
function abc() {
  var i = 1;
  var img = document.getElementsByName('faceImg')[0];

  // initialize interval and keep reference to clear inerval
  // also keep reference to the callback for calling initially
  var refInt = setInterval(callback = function() {
    // generate source
    var ImageSrc = i + ".png";
    // update source
    img.src = 'http://img.pranavc.in/100?t=' + ImageSrc;

    // clear interval based on when i reached 6
    if (i++ == 6) clearInterval(refInt); // or if (++i == 7)
  // set the delay here
  }, 1000);

  // call the callback for initial image, you can avoid
  // if you don't need to show image on initially
  callback();
}

abc();
```

```html
<img name=faceImg width=100 height=100>
```

---

With ES6 syntax:

```js
let i = 1;
const img = document.getElementsByName('faceImg')[0];

const callback = () => {
  img.src = 'http://img.pranavc.in/100?t=' + i + ".png";
  if (i++ === 6) clearInterval(refInt);
}
const refInt = setInterval(callback, 1000);

callback();
```

```html
<img name=faceImg width=100 height=100>
```

Comment: You have to remove "int" from "intsetInterval" ;)

Comment: Should be `if (i++ == 6) clearInterval(refInt);` OP wants to display image 6 as well I believe.

Answer (score 0):

In your function

```
function abc(){
var i = 1;
while(i<=6){
    var ImageSrc = i + ".png";
    console.log(ImageSrc);
    document.getElementsByName('faceImg')[0].src = ImageSrc;
    i += 1;
    //sleep(1000);
}
//document.getElementsByName('faceImg')[0].src = ImageSrc;
}
```

you are initializing the i variable as counter but you have not used it in the loop here

```
document.getElementsByName('faceImg')[0].src = ImageSrc;
```

change this [0] to [i] the counter you have initialized.

```
document.getElementsByName('faceImg')[i].src = ImageSrc;
```

Answer (score 0):

you are putting everything on index 0

`[0].src = ImageSrc`

you need to have the `i` instead of `0` as

```
 document.getElementsByName('faceImg')[i].src = ImageSrc;
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
document.getElementsByName('faceImg')[0].src = ImageSrc;
```

To

```
document.getElementsByName('faceImg')[i].src = ImageSrc;
```

also use

```
let ImageSrc = i + ".png";
```

instead of

```
 var ImageSrc = i + ".png";
```